# How to prove that $H(X, Y) + H(Y, Z) \geq H(X,Z) + H(Y)$

Tags: information-theory, entropy

If H is the entropy function (information theory), then what is a simple way to prove that

$H(X, Y) + H(Y, Z) \geq H(X,Z) + H(Y)$

for all random variables $X, Y, Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
   H(X,Y) + H(Y,Z) &=
      \overbrace{H(Y) + H(X|Y)} + H(Y,Z) \\
   &\geq
      H(Y) + \underbrace{H(X|Y,Z) + H(Y,Z)} \\
   &=
      H(Y) + H(X,Y,Z) \\
   &\geq
      H(Y) + H(X,Z)
\end{align*}